# Google Apps Script: Create a new column in array based on value of other columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have an array that I pulled from a google sheet. It essentially reports on the performance of my client's Instagram posts. The first column in the array gives an image url and the second column gives a video url depending on if the post was an image or a video. A truncated version of the array will look like this:

```
[ [ 'Media URL',
    'Video thumbnail URL',    
    'Engagement',
    'Media impressions',
    'Media reach' ],
  [ 'www.sampleimageurl.com/1',
    '',
    1328,
    23359,
    22234 ],
  [ '',
    'www.samplevideourl.com/2',
    683,
    12542,
    11743 ],
  [ 'www.sampleimageurl.com/3',
    '',
    1070,
    15232,
    11863 ]]
```

In this array, either the 'Media URL' will have a value in it OR the 'Video thumbnail URL' will have a value in it - there will never be a condition in which either both have a value or none of them have a value.

I need your help to figure out a way to combine the values of the 'Media URL' & 'Video thumbnail URL'.
The new array would look something like this:

```
[ [ 'URL',
    'Engagement',
    'Media impressions',
    'Media reach' ],
  [ 'www.sampleimageurl.com/1',
    1328,
    23359,
    22234 ],
  [ 'www.samplevideourl.com/2',
    683,
    12542,
    11743 ],
  [ 'www.sampleimageurl.com/3',
    1070,
    15232,
    11863 ]]
```

I've been experimenting with creating an empty array `var newArray = []` and filling it up using an if condition with splice but i'm getting nowhere with this approach.

```
for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i]
    if (row[1] === "") {
      newArray.push(row.splice(1,1))
    }
    else {
      newArray.push(row.splice(0,1))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
A.map(item => { item[0] = item[0] || item [1];  item.splice(1, 1); });
A[0][0]="URL";
```

Live code: https://runkit.com/embed/iixibhqj5sg0

[image]

Full code snippet:

```js
const A = [
[ 'Media URL',
'Video thumbnail URL',    
'Engagement',
'Media impressions',
'Media reach' ],
[ 'www.sampleimageurl.com/1',
'',
1328,
23359,
22234 ],
  [ '',
'www.samplevideourl.com/2',
683,
12542,
11743 ],
  [ 'www.sampleimageurl.com/3',
'',
1070,
15232,
11863 ]];

A.map(item => { item[0] = item[0] || item [1];  item.splice(1, 1); });
A[0][0]="URL";
console.log(A);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no other column is empty, You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const data = [ [ 'Media URL',
'Video thumbnail URL',    
'Engagement',
'Media impressions',
'Media reach' ],
  [ 'www.sampleimageurl.com/1',
'',
1328,
23359,
22234 ],
  [ '',
'www.samplevideourl.com/2',
683,
12542,
11743 ],
  [ 'www.sampleimageurl.com/3',
'',
1070,
15232,
11863 ]];

data[0][0] = "URL";
data[0][1] = "";
const output = data.map(row => row.filter(col => col !==""));
console.info(output);
```

Comment: Note: The above code will not run on deprecated ES5 engine. To use the code, [upgrade to modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).

Answer (score 1):

```
function kreatiefMetKurk(){

 var array = [ [ 'Media URL',
'Video thumbnail URL',    
'Engagement',
'Media impressions',
'Media reach' ],
  [ 'www.sampleimageurl.com/1',
'',
1328,
23359,
22234 ],
  [ '',
'www.samplevideourl.com/2',
683,
12542,
11743 ],
  [ 'www.sampleimageurl.com/3',
'',
1070,
15232,
11863 ]]; 

array.map(function(row){row[1] = (row[0]+row[1]).trim(); 
                        row.shift(); 
                        return row;})

}
```